# What does $\nabla'$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coordinate-systems, differentiation, notation

In D.J Griffiths Electrodynamics (Page 173) it says, $\nabla' |\vec{x}| = \frac{\hat{x}}{x^2}$. However by my calculation $\nabla |\vec{x}| = -\frac{\hat{x}}{x^2}$ so what does the $\nabla'$ signify?

Comment: $\nabla '$ corresponds to Laplacian in x' coordinates

Comment: Can you provide the direct quote?

Comment: Like @KP99 said, $\nabla'$ is the Laplacian with respect to primed coordinates. Is $\vec x$ defined in terms of $\vec x'$?

Comment: How is it a Laplacian? The symbol for Laplacian is $\Delta$ or $\nabla^2$ and gives a scalar, not a vector. It's the gradient in $x'$ coordinates.